# "Pattern-matching" types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I want a function `f` that acts as an increment on `Int`s and as an identity on all the other types. I tried to enable the `TypeApplications` extension and do this the most straight-forward way possible:

```
f :: forall a. a -> a
f @Int x = x + 1
f @_   x = x
```

But the extension does not enable such patterns:

```
<interactive>:6:1: error: Parse error in pattern: f @Int
```

Is there pattern-matching for types (or a similar mechanism) in Haskell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated, this is impossible to achieve in Haskell since it would violate one of the fundamental properties of parametric polymorphism known as "parametricity", which ensures that any polymorphic function satisfies a specific property knows as the "free theorem".

In particular, a terminating function of type `forall a. a -> a` must be the identity. There are no other possible implementations.

That being said, if we allow a constraint on type `a`, this becomes possible. Typically, run-time type-testing is done in Haskell through the `Typeable` type class:

```
f :: forall a. Typeable a => a -> a
f x = case eqT @a @Int of    -- Is a ~ Int ?
   Just Refl -> x + 1        -- If it is, we can add one.
   Nothing   -> x            -- Otherwise, return x as-is.
```

This requires a bunch of GHC extensions, and to import [`Data.Typeable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html).

Answer (score 8):

There is, but you cannot have a fall-through pattern like you can at the computation level. That is, at the computation level, I could write

```
f 0 = 42
f n = n-1
```

with a fall-through pattern `n` that works *exactly* when none of the other patterns matched. At the type-level, you can't do this -- even nested inside other patterns. You can have a pattern that matches anything, but not "anything else" -- if you match anything, you can't have any other patterns.

So, once you have the collection of patterns you want to match against, you can write a type class and instances. So, if you want to support `Int`, `Bool`, and lists, you could write:

```
class F a where f :: a -> a
instance F Int where f = succ
instance F Bool where f = id
instance F [a] where f = id
```

The last shows an example of what I meant before, where you can have a pattern that matches anything, but not a pattern that matches "anything else": `[a]` is a fine instance, but it precludes the creation of a `[Bool]` instance later.

Answer (score 2):

Here you’re trying to produce different *term-level* code based on *type-level* information, so you need a typeclass; and you’re trying to match on types, so you can use an associated *type family*. This method requires overlapping instances:

```
{-# Language
    AllowAmbiguousTypes,
    FlexibleInstances,
    TypeFamilies #-}

-- The class of overloads of ‘f’.
class F a where
  type family T a   -- Or: ‘type T a’
  f :: T a -> T a

-- The “default” catch-all overload.
instance {-# Overlappable #-} F a where
  type instance T a = a  -- Or: ‘type T a = a’
  f x = x

-- More specific instance, selected when ‘a ~ Int’.
instance {-# Overlapping #-} F Int where
  type instance T Int = Int
  f x = x + 1
```

Then `f @Int 1` gives `2`, and `f 'c'` gives `'c'`.

But in this case, type family is unnecessary because it happens to be the identity—I include it for the sake of giving a point of generalisation. If you want to produce *types* by pattern-matching on types just like a function, then a closed type family is a great fit:

```
{-# Language
    KindSignatures,
    TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Int
import Data.Word
import Data.Kind (Type)

type family Unsigned (a :: Type) :: Type where
  Unsigned Int   = Word
  Unsigned Int8  = Word8
  Unsigned Int16 = Word16
  Unsigned Int32 = Word32
  Unsigned Int64 = Word64
  Unsigned a     = a
```

Back to your question, here’s the original example with plain typeclasses:

```
class F a where
  f :: a -> a

instance {-# Overlappable #-} F a where
  f x = x

instance {-# Overlapping #-} F Int where
  f x = x + 1
```

Unfortunately, there’s no notion of a “closed typeclass” that would allow you to avoid the overlapping instances. In this case it’s fairly benign, but problems with coherence can arise with more complex cases, especially with `MultiParamTypeClasses`. In general it’s preferable to [add a new method instead of writing overlapping instances](http://brandon.si/code/how-the-haskell-prelude-avoids-overlapping-types-in-show/) when possible.

Note that in either case, `f` now has an `F a` constraint, e.g. the latter is `(F a) => a -> a`. You can’t avoid *some* change in the type; in Haskell, polymorphic means *parametrically* polymorphic, to preserve the property that types can be erased at compile time.

Other options include a GADT:

```
data FArg a where
  FInt :: Int -> FArg Int
  FAny :: a -> FArg a

f :: FArg a -> a
f (FInt x) = x + 1  -- Here we have ‘a ~ Int’ in scope.
f (FAny x) = x
```

Or (already mentioned in other answers) a `Typeable` constraint for dynamic typing:

```
{-# Language
    BlockArguments,
    ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Typeable (Typeable, eqT)
import Data.Type.Equality ((:~:)(Refl))

f :: forall a. (Typeable a) => a -> a
f x = fromMaybe x do
  Refl <- eqT @a @Int
  pure (x + 1)
```