# Free theorem for fmap

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory, denotational-semantics, free-theorem

Consider the following wrapper:

```
newtype F a = Wrap { unwrap :: Int }
```

I want to disprove (as an exercise to wrap my head around [this interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67197914/11143763)) that there’s a legitimate `Functor F` instance which allows us to apply functions of `Int -> Int` type to the actual contents and to *~ignore~* all other functions (i. e. `fmap nonIntInt = id`).

I believe this should be done with a free theorem for `fmap` (which I read [here](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/snippets/fmap)):
for given `f`, `g`, `h` and `k`, such that `g . f = k . h`: `$map g . fmap f = fmap k . $map h`, where `$map` is the **natural map** for the given constructor.

What defines a **natural map**? Am I right to assume that it is a simple `flip const` for `F`?

As far as I get it: `$map f` is what we denote as `Ff` in category theory. Thus, in a categorical sense, we simply want something among the lines of the following diagram to commute:
[image]

Yet, I do not know what to put instead of `???`s (that is, what functor do we apply to get such a diagram and how do we denote this *almost-`fmap`*?).

So, what is a **natural map** in general, and for `F`? What is the proper diagram for `fmap`'s free theorem?

---

### Where am I going with this?

Consider:

```
f = const 42
g = id

h    = const ()
k () = 42
```

It is easy to see that `f . g` is `h . k`. And yet, the *non-existant `fmap`* will *execute* only `f`, not `k`, giving different results. If my intuition about the **naturality** is correct, such a proof would work. That's what I am trying to figure out.

[@leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) proposed a simpler piece of proof: `fmap show . fmap (+1)` alters the contents, unlike `fmap $ show . (+1)`. It is a nice piece of proof, and yet I would still like to work with free theorems as an exercise.

Comment: I don't see where you're going with this natural map stuff. You just need to show, for the functor instance you described, a counterexample where `fmap f . fmap g ≠ fmap (f . g)`. That's easy to do.

Comment: How does one write an `fmap f (Wrap x)` that distinguishes between `f :: Int -> Int` and all the other function types for `f`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout oh, that's a good idea. So, we're taking `g = (+1)` and `f = show`, so `fmap (f . g)` does not alter the contents, unlike `fmap f . fmap g`. Thank you, and yet I still want to do this using the free theorem as, as I mentioned in the post, this is a mere exercise to understand this whole thing with free theorems :). Besides, if my understanding of *naturality* is correct, the proof using thee free theorem is not way harder: consider `f = const 42`, `g = id`, `h = const ()` and `k ~() = 42`. I will add both those proofs to the post.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann one can't, and that's what we're trying to prove formally :).

Comment: `const 42` has type `Int->Int` and also `()->Int` and any type `a->Int` for all types `a`. What should `fmap (const 42) (Wrap 0)` be?

Comment: Parametricity is not dependent on Hask. If you want to prove a theorem about what *every* function of type `(a->b) -> Wrap a -> Wrap b` can and cannot do, you probably should open the Wadler's paper and see how such results are proved there. Whether such function is intended to serve as `fmap` is irrelevant to the eventual proof, thus no need to draw commutative diagrams and stuff.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. concerning your first comment: you are right, I took some liberty not to overburden the text. And yet, whether we allow `forall a. a -> Int` to be interpreted as `Int -> Int` or not, I don't think it will make much difference as the counterexamples would just involve same functions with more narrow or broad type signatures.

Comment: OTOH category theory doesn't depend on parametricity. The function you are talking about cannot serve as `fmap` even if you somehow manage to write non-parametric functions (for example, a compiler extension supplies you with a magic non-parametric function you can build upon). This is what @leftaroundabout proves.

Comment: You cannot write a function that depending on the type signature you supply produces different results. Is this what you want to prove?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. concerning your last comment: yes, that's right. In a particular case for a `fmap`.

Comment: So you probably should ask that question and get rid of the categorical red herring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231571/discussion-between-zhiltsoff-igor-and-n-pronouns-m).

Answer (score 3):

So we are entertaining a function `m :: forall a b . (a->b) -> F a -> F b` such that (among other things)

```
m (1 +)    (Wrap x) = (Wrap (1+x))
m (show)   (Wrap x) = (Wrap x)
```

There are two somewhat related questions here.

1. Can a well-behaved `fmap` do this?
2. Can a parametric function do this?

The answer to both questions is "no".

A well-behaved `fmap` can't do this because `fmap` has to obey the axioms of `Functor`. Whether our environment is parametric or not is irrelevant. The axiom of `Functor` says that for all functions `a` and `b`, `fmap (a . b) = fmap a . fmap b` must hold, and this fails for `a = show` and `b = (1 +)`. So `m` cannot be a well-behaved `fmap`.

A parametric function can't do this because that is what the parametricity theorem says. When viewing types as relations between terms, related functions take related arguments to related results. It is easy to see that `m` fails parametricity, but it is slightly easier to look at `m': forall a b. (a -> b) -> (Int -> Int)` (the two can be trivially converted to each other). `(1 +)` is related to `show` because `m'` is polymorphic in its argument, so different values of the argument can be related by *any* relation. Functions are relations, and there exists a function that sends `(1 +)` to `show`. However, the result type of `m'` has no type variables, so it corresponds to the constant relation (its values are only related to themselves). Since every value including `m'` is related to itself, it follows that all parametric functions `m :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> (Int -> Int)` must obey `m f = m g`, i.e. they must ignore their first argument. Which is intuitively obvious since there is nothing to apply it to.

One can in fact deduce the first statement from the second by observing that a well-behaved `fmap` must be parametric. So even if the language allows non-parametricity, `fmap` cannot make any non-trivial use of it.

Comment: Aha, so, to sum up, my attempt to do this via categories was faulty as parametricity is not required by category theory (see your comment under the main post). The right way would've been to consider this `fmap` to be the functor's map for arrows and show that the `fmap (a . b) = fmap a . fmap b` law doesn't hold. Did I describe my mistake correctly?

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor In fact parametricity seems to be required for `fmap`, because `fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g` is strictly stronger than the parametricity condition (I think; need to verify this...)

Comment: I believe that the second functor law follows from the first functor law plus the parametricity condition.

Comment: Also, can you, please touch upon the notion of **naturality** discussed in the question? The one about finding our whether `$map` for `F` is simply `flip const`.

Comment: Does [this here reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2w05a0/edward_kmett_the_free_theorem_for_fmap/) help?

Comment: It does, thank you. Yet, I don't feel too confident about fully getting it. Not to extend our discussion here, I made [a post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67314984/natural-map-derivation-algorithm).